# How to get rendered html on ActionFilter

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

i'm creating a ActionFilter on ASP.NET MVC4 that i want to use for Caching purposes.

my goal is how to get the final rendered Html on the OnActionExecuted(or somewhere else) and store it on cache.

my problem is that when i what to read httpcontext.response.output (stream) it is write only.

some ideas?